# Facebook Comments Moderation Tool not enabled

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I have Facebook Comments on internal page - you have to login to see it. I configured it according to docs (I believe). Comments widget is displayed. I can add comments from different accounts and I can see them but there is no Moderation Tool button and comments are not shown on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/ I tried 3 configurations. None worked for me. What am I doing wrong?

## Configuration 1

#### In head

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="facebook admins"/>
```

#### After opening body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

#### Later on page

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="url to this specific article" data-width="100%"></div>
```

## Configuration 2

#### In head

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="facebook app id"/>
```

#### After opening body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=facebook app id";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

#### Later on page

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="url to this specific article" data-width="100%"></div>
```

## Configuration 3 (mix of both)

#### In head

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="facebook app id"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="facebook admins"/>
```

#### After opening body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=facebook app id";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

#### Later on page

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="url to this specific article" data-width="100%"></div>
```

## Common app settings

[image]

## Comments widget on my page when I (admin) am logged in

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. I also tried all combination.

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Paste the url.
The problem will be shown in "Warnings That Should Be Fixed"

I had a problem with app_id.

Also, you can specify either fb:app_id or fb:admins, but not both.